# Capitalization of "Subsection"

Tags: writing, grammar

I write a mathematical paper. Do you capitalize "subsection" when you refer to a specific subsection? For example, I would write:

```
"In Subsection 3 we show ..."
```

But I would write:

```
"In the previous subsection we showed that ..."
```

What is the consensus on that issue?

Comment: I would not capitalise in either case and my supervisor would probably complain if I did. Similarly, figure 3 or Figure 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it right.  Think of it like proper nouns vs. pronouns.  Compare:

> Mr. Jones told me about types of stars; then he explained how they burn hydrogen.

and

> Subsection 3 explains about types of stars; the next subsection explains how they burn hydrogen.